# Changing GroupBy keys depending on Class Structure

Tags: c#, group-by

I have a list of items with multiple columns and would like to group them by some fields depending on a boolean:

I have the following class:

```
public class Item
    {
        public string Group { get; set; }
        public string Person { get; set; }
        public string Currency { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
        public string OtherAdd { get; set; }
        public string Income { get; set; }
    }
```

which is part of a List:

```
var results = items.ToList(); //items is IEnumerable<Item>
```

if `int type = 1`, then I want to group by more elements:

```
results = results
                .GroupBy(e => new { e.Group, e.Person, e.Branch, e.Currency, e.Country, e.County, e.OtherAdd})
                .Select(g => new Item
                {
                    Group = g.Key.Group,
                    Person = g.Key.Person,
                    Currency = g.Key.Currency,
                    Currency = g.Key.Country,
                    Currency = g.Key.County,
                    Currency = g.Key.OtherAdd,
                    Income = g.Sum(p => double.Parse(p.Income, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToString("0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                })
                .ToList();
```

if `int type = 2`, then I want to group by fewer elements (e.g. because OtherAdd would be an empty String):

```
results = results
                .GroupBy(e => new { e.Group, e.Person, e.Branch, e.Currency})
                .Select(g => new Item
                {
                    Group = g.Key.Group,
                    Person = g.Key.Person,
                    Currency = g.Key.Currency,
                    Income = g.Sum(p => double.Parse(p.Income, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToString("0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                })
                .ToList();
```

etc.

Is there a way for me to change the GroupBy key depending on my integer type without repeating the code?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: what wrong with simple `if`?

Comment: I actually have at least 6 different types, so I would need to repeat the same code for all 6 types. I thought there might be a nicer solution to this

Comment: It's not the same code. Not by far. Even if it were possible to compose `GroupBy` and `Select` the way you want, I doubt it would help in any way. Unless you can organize your classes differently to exploit the similarities, there really isn't much point.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use the old SQL trick, conditional values:

```
.GroupBy(e => new { e.Group, Person = (e.Type == 1 ? e.Person : Guid.NewGuid().ToString()), ... }
```

While this will still include the columns in the group by, all the items will have unique keys, so it doesn't quite matter. Sadly, I don't think there's a way around generating the unique keys, unlike in SQL (where you could just use `NULL`).

A better way might be to implement your own grouping class, instead of using an anonymous type. You could then use your own equality and hashing semantics, to make sure whether you include all the fields or not. However, that is arguably going to be more work than just having the similar code repeated.

Or, you might want to revise your whole design. It doesn't sound like what you're trying to do makes much sense - it's already quite suspicious that you're using the same type for two different things, and using `string`s for all the fields doesn't help either. Maybe you could try a different object design?

Comment: are you try it? _Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access._

Comment: The `Item` class doesn't have a `Type` property.  I think `type` is a separate variable.

Comment: Yes juharr is right. Sorry if I didn't make that clear